# jQuery - Toggle Multiple Images & Maintain div Height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using an on click function to toggle between 2 images and it is working like a charm but I was wondering how I would add more images to the sequence? The second part of my question is, is it possible to maintain the height of the div when toggling between the images as it currently collapses the height to (display: none) during the transition.

```
$('#image').on('click', function() {
  let src = ($(this).attr('src') === 'image/1.jpg')
    ? 'image/1.jpg'
    : 'image/2.jpg';

  $(this)
    .fadeOut(500, () => $(this).attr('src', src))
    .fadeIn(500);
});
```

Thank you all for your help!

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/camusahn/u4rspwya/

Comment: Can you share fiddle or snippet?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can store your images in an array then pick randomly on click. Just take a look on what I have done though in my codepen:

https://codepen.io/jcarizon/pen/MWWLyOP

```css
$('#image').on('click', function() {
  const images = [
    "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/fff000/ffffff",
    "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/ff0000/ffffff",
    "https://dummyimage.com/100x100/0f0f11/ffffff"
  ];
  const randomImages = images[Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length)];

  let src = randomImages;

  $(this)
    .fadeOut(500, () => $(this).attr('src', src))
    .fadeIn(500);
});
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/ffffff" alt="dummy" />
```

Comment: You can as well keep track of the current image src and then use that to avoid showing the same image consecutively.

Comment: @BankiLouis
sorry to bother but how would you keep track of the current image src?

Comment: @Banki Louis camusahn Please take a look again to the codepen. I updated a line on the src variable.

Comment: Glad it helped :)